# Нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

Нужна ли запятая перед словом "все" — "Да и вообще все перестало иметь смысл"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В русском языке совсем не много вводных слов, которые в другом контексте таковыми не являются.  Большинство вводных слов могут быть и членами предложения, причем даже в том же самом контексте. Сравните:  Врач может быть сейчас у себя в кабинете. — Врач, может быть, сейчас у себя в кабинете. И, прочитав такое предложение без запятых, как можно догадаться о смысле? Только автор, только говорящий может решить, вводное оно или нет.

То же относится и к слову вообще.  Слово вообще является вводным и обособляется, если оно употреблено в значении «вообще говоря». . В других случаях слово вообще употребляется как наречие в разных значениях: Пушкин для русского искусства то же, что Ломоносов для русского просвещения вообще (Гонч.) («в общем», «в целом»); Разжигать костры он вообще запрещал (Каз.) («всегда», «совсем», «при всех условиях»); .. Он вообще смотрел чудаком (Т.) («во всех отношениях», «по отношению ко всему»). (Примеры из Розенталя). 
Выбирайте, какое значение Вам подходит и решайте. *Вообще говоря, все перестало иметь смысл.* Или *Совсем все перестало иметь смысл.*